# Why is this a valid step (expectation w.r.t posterior)?

Tags: probability, bayesian, expected-value, integral

Reading through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00473.pdf) and on page 10 they use the step:

$$\int q(\theta|D,\phi) \log p(Y|X,\theta) d\theta = E_q \log p(Y|X,\theta)$$

Now obviously I understand why they have written this as an expectation, since they are integrating $\log p(Y|X,\theta)$ with respect to the density of $q(\theta|D,\phi)$.

My question is how can we use this step when the $\log p(Y|X,\theta)$ term itself depends on $\theta$? Shouldn't $\theta$ be integrated out? I don't understand how this step is valid as it seems to be ignoring the fact $\log p(Y|X,\theta)$ also depends on $\theta$?

Comment: Please make the question self-contained so that it makes sense without reading the linked reference.

Answer (score 1):

In$$\int q(\theta|D,\phi) \log p(Y|X,\theta) \,\text{d}\theta = \mathbb{E}_q \left[ \log p(Y|X,\theta) \right]$$the expectation is understood as computed as an expectation for the distribution on $\theta$ with density $q(\theta|D,\phi)$, which means that the right-hand term depends on $Y$, $X$, $D$, and $\phi$. Thus $\theta$ is correctly integrated out.